# Changing Bootstrap 'loading' style progress bar to dot style progress bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am currently using a Bootstrap "loading" style progress bar to indicate the progress of a survey. The progress bar code looks like this:

```html
<div class="progress" style="height: 20px;">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

However, I would like to change the style of the progress bar to a dot style, where each step of the survey is represented by a dot. For example:

[image]

I have searched through Bootstrap documentation and tried different CSS styles, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to achieve the dot style. Can someone please guide me on how to modify the progress bar to display as dots rather than a solid bar? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I created it from scratch. If you have any question feel free to ask.

```js
const previous = document.querySelector('.previous');
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');

let counter = 0;

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(counter <= 35){
        progress.innerHTML += "⚫";
        counter++;
    }
})

previous.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(counter > 0){
        const textNode = progress.firstChild;
        textNode.data = textNode.data.slice(0, -1);
    }
})
```

```css
.progress{
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
<button class="previous">Previous</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```